# Elasticsearch 2.0: how to delete by query in Java

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to upgrade to ES 2.0. I have downloaed ES 2.0 and installed it on my Windows machine.

In my pom.xml, I have the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>delete-by-query</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>
```

In my Java code, I did delete by query in the following way when using ES 1.7.3:

```
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("");
    b.append("{");
    b.append("  \"query\": {");  
    b.append("      \"term\": {");
    b.append("          \"category\": " + category_value );
    b.append("      }");
    b.append("  }");
    b.append("}");

    client = getClient(); 

    DeleteByQueryResponse response = client.prepareDeleteByQuery("myindex")
                .setTypes("mydocytype")
                .setSource(b.toString())
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

I am hoping to replace this:

```
    DeleteByQueryResponse response = client.prepareDeleteByQuery("myindex")
                .setTypes("mydocytype")
                .setSource(b.toString())
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

with ES 2.0 way. Googled but failed to find an example for it. The online API documentation seems too abstract to me. How can I do it?

Another question: Do I have to install delete-by-query plugin in Elasticsearch server?

Thanks for any pointer!

**UPDATE**

I followed Max's suggestion, and here is what I have now:

First, when create the client, make settings look like the following:

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("cluster.name", "mycluster")
                        .put("plugin.types", DeleteByQueryPlugin.class.getName())
                        .build();
```

Second, at the place doing delete-by-query:

```
    DeleteByQueryResponse rsp = new DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder(client, DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE)
    .setIndices("myindex")
    .setTypes("mydoctype")
    .setSource(b.toString())
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

I also installed delete by query plugin by running the following in the root directory of ES:

```
bin\plugin install delete-by-query
```

I get errors if I do not install this plugin.

After all these steps, ES related parts work just fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you can use this:

```
     DeleteByQueryResponse rsp = new DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder(client, DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE)
            .setTypes("mydocytype")
            .setSource(b.toString())
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

You have to add plugin type to your settings:

```
     Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                         .put("plugin.types", DeleteByQueryPlugin.class.getName())
```

If you have remote server you have to install the plugin.

Comment: Hello Max, thanks for helping me out! What do you mean by "using local node"? I have everything on my notebook. The Java web app runs on port 8080 and ES runs on port 9300. I have to manually start the two one by one. Another thing: Your settings statement is in error. I updated my code, and always got null pointer error.

Comment: Hello, with the local node I meant using embedded ES node (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/node-client.html).  When you use this you don't have to start another elasticsearch client.
I think you are connecting to your elasticsearch node using transport client(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html).
Where exactly do you get null pointer ?

Comment: Ok I see that even if you don't use embedded node you have to put plugin.types. I am editing my comment for this.

Comment: Max, thanks for follow-up and making your answer clearer. Really really really appreciate it! I got my code working now due to your help. Best.

Comment: I get an NPE when I use the delete-by-query plugin with the `TransportClient`. Happens regardless if I add the plugin type to the settings or not.

Answer (score 12):

`plugin.types` have been deprecated in ES 2.1.0 ([source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/13055)). So the accepted solution will result in a `NullPointerException`.

The solution is to use the `addPlugin` method:

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings())
                .addPlugin(DeleteByQueryPlugin.class)
                .build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host",9300));
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "adding the plugin" on the client side as well?

Answer (score 6):

From Elastic 5 in onwards...

```
final BulkIndexByScrollResponse response = DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(super.transportClient)
                    .filter(
                            QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                                    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("_type", "MY_TYPE")) // Trick to define and ensure the type.
                                    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("...", "...")))
                    .source("MY_INDEX")
                    .get();

    return response.getDeleted() > 0;
```

[Oficial documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-delete-by-query.html)

Comment: Dani, thanks for the info. Good to know for upgrade. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

firstly:
 add elasticsearch-2.3.3/plugins/delete-by-query/delete-by-query-2.3.3.jar to build path.

then:

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings)
                .addPlugin(DeleteByQueryPlugin.class)
                .build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                        InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.224"), 9300));
```