# Delete Indexes by index name and type using elasticSearch 2.3.3 in java

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, java

I have a project in java where I index the data using elastic search 2.3.3. The indexes are of two types.

My index doc looks like:

```
{
   "took": 10,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
  "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
        {
           "_index": "test_index",
           "_type": "movies",
           "_id": "uReb0g9KSLKS18sTATdr3A",
           "_score": 1,
           "_source": {
              "genre": "Thriller"
            }
       },
       {
           "_index": "test_index",
           "_type": "drama",
           "_id": "cReb0g9KSKLS18sTATdr3B",
           "_score": 1,
           "_source": {
              "genre": "SuperNatural"
            }
        },
        {
           "_index": "index1",
           "_type": "drama",
           "_id": "cReb0g9KSKLS18sT76ng3B",
           "_score": 1,
           "_source": {
              "genre": "Romance"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I need to delete index of a particular name and type only.

**For eg:-** From the above doc, I want to delete indexes with Name **"test_index"** and type **"drama"**.

So the result should look like:

```
{
   "took": 10,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
  "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
        {
           "_index": "test_index",
           "_type": "movies",
           "_id": "uReb0g9KSLKS18sTATdr3A",
           "_score": 1,
           "_source": {
              "genre": "Thriller"
            }
       },
       {
           "_index": "index1",
           "_type": "drama",
           "_id": "cReb0g9KSKLS18sT76ng3B",
           "_score": 1,
           "_source": {
              "genre": "Romance"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Solutions tried:**

**client.admin().indices().delete(new DeleteIndexRequest("test_index").actionGet();**

But it delete both indexes with name "test_index"

I have also tried various queries in **sense beta plugin** like:

**DELETE /test_index/drama**

It gives the error: **No handler found for uri [/test_index/drama] and method [DELETE]**

**DELETE /test_index/drama/_query?q=_id:*&analyze_wildcard=true**

It also doesn't work.

When I fire delete index request at that time id of indexes are unknown to us and I have to delete the indexes by name and type only.

**How can I delete the required indexes using java api?**

Comment: Have you installed the [delete-by-query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html)? The latest query works for me and deletes only the documents from `test_index/drama`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to be possible till ES 2.0 using the delete mapping API, however since 2.0 `Delete Mapping` API does not exist any more.
To do this you will have to install the [Delete by Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/delete-by-query-usage.html) plugin. Then you can simply do a match all query on your index and type and then delete all of them.

The query will look something like this:

```
DELETE /test_index/drama/_query
{
  "query": { 
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Also keep in mind that this will delete the documents in the mapping and not the mapping itself. If you want to remove the mapping too you'll have to reindex without the mapping.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430240/elasticsearch-2-0-how-to-delete-by-query-in-java) might be able to help you with the java implementation